# List of lists of each row from SQL database using Entity Framework & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, list

I have database and I'm using Entity Framework to create models (database first). I want to loop somehow through my model so that I can create a list of each row. Then I want to create list of those lists. Also lists have to be lists of objects not strings.

Model class:

```
public class person
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Code {get; set;}
    public int Time {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have such a person in the database and I want to create a list that contains ID, Code, Time and Name taken from one row. And then I want to create a list of those Person lists. I assume that I should use foreach or for loop but I don't know how should I start.

Edit:
I have database that looks like this:

```
ID | Code | Time | Name
 1    200    10    Paul
 2    201    20    Tom
 3    203    25    Jacob
 4    208    10    Agnes
```

Now i want to create a list with one row. That list should look like:

```
List<1,200,10,Paul>
```

Then i want to create or rather add to list of lists each list created from those rows. So that i would have list that contains lists of Persons.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want a list of people your can get that with something like `context.Persons.ToList();` This will return a `List<Person>`. You would use [foreach](http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/foreach-loop-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view-engine-example) in your view to loop through that list.

Comment: I need that list of lists in controller to do other things with it.

Comment: Still not sure what "list of lists" means. You have only shown a person model with no relationships so all you can really get is a `List<Person>`. It seems to me you are using MVC. So in your controller GET you would fill a list of persons from the context as shown. Then you would pass and display this in a View with foreach. More info needed...

Comment: I don't need to pass it to view. I want to create List<List<Person>>.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. If you have `List<List<Person>>`, what is inside each `List<Person>` that separates it from the others?

Comment: OK, I added an answer that shows an example.

Comment: I edited my question with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no legitimate reason to do this, but perhaps this is what you mean?

```
var listOfLists = db.Persons.Select(p => new List<object> {
    (object)p.ID,
    (object)p.Code,
    (object)p.Time,
    (object)p.Name
}).ToList();
```

Comment: But what does it create? List of all ids, list of all Codes etc?

Comment: This creates a `List<object>` from each row, and then creates a `List<List<object>>` from those, which is what your question states. If that isn't what is desired, I would improve your question, including adding examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just go through list of Person's data item you need just foreach:

```
foreach(var data in ctx.Persons.Select( p => new {p.ID, p.Code, p.Time, p. Name})){
    // here you have data object with 4 items
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i don't want anonymous types. Can i specify types of these 4 objects?

Comment: The four objects have types. You can specify a class instead of having an anonymous object, but then you are back to just using `List<Person>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to create a `<List<List<Person>>`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PersonIndex()
{
    List<List<Person>> personLists = new List<List<Person>>();
    var personsCodeA = context.Persons.Where(p => p.Code == "A").ToList();
    var personsCodeB = context.Persons.Where(p => p.Code == "B").ToList();
    var personsCodeX = context.Persons.Where(p => p.Code == "X").ToList();
    personLists.Add(personsCodeA);
    personLists.Add(personsCodeB);
    personLists.Add(personsCodeX);
    return View(personLists);
}
```

Now in the view (or where ever) you could do:

```
foreach (var currentList in personLists)
{
    // process each list
    console.writeline(string.Format("People in code {0}:",currentList[0].Code));  //todo null check
    foreach (var person in currentList])
    {
        // process each person in the current list
        console.writeline(string.Format("  Person: {0}",person.Name));  //todo null check
        var personID = person.ID;
        var personCode = person.Code;
        var personName = person.Name;
        var personTime = person.Time;
    }
}
```